# How to display timer while recording -flutter

Tags: flutter

im creating a chat app. **I want to display my timer (**Widget buildPlayer()**) when the record button is started** and stop when I click stop icon. currently the button is toggling start to stop. but I want to display timer while recording.  how can I do this. [chatRoom.dart](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cvFXrm--fikXU2cf6NKXq2g2Te8HLiGT-S6dA7HVDh4/edit?usp=sharing)

I have already implemented TimerWidget separately and access it via **timercontroller**. [timer_widget.dart](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zy2VyKSP4p9d---i9IgwX3SL-ESAa7vHARzShWxEFfg/edit?usp=sharing)

appreciate your help on this. you can refer my full chatRoom.dart code from above link if you want. please let me know a way to do this.

```
Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: Container(

                            height: 49,
                            width: 49,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              color: mainGreen,

                            ),

                            child: IconButton(

                                onPressed: () async {
                                  await recorder.toggleRecording();
                                  final isRecording = recorder.isRecording;
                                  setState(() {});
                                  if (isRecording) {
                                    timerController.startTimer();
                                  } else {
                                    timerController.stoptTimer();
                                  }
                                },
                                icon: Icon(icon, color: Colors.white,)
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),




 Widget buildPlayer() {
    final text = recorder.isRecording ? 'Now Recording' : 'Press Start';
     final animate = recorder.isRecording;

    return  CircleAvatar(
      radius :92,
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.mic, size: 32),
            TimerWidget(controller: timerController),
            SizedBox(height: 8),
            Text(text),
          ]
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented like this,

```
  Stream<int>? timerStream;
  StreamSubscription<int>? timerSubscription;
  String minutesStr = '00';
  String secondsStr = '00';
  
  
// At Recording Start:
  
timerStream = stopWatchStream();
timerSubscription = timerStream!.listen((int newTick) {
  setState(() {
    minutesStr = ((newTick / 60) % 60).floor().toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    secondsStr = (newTick % 60).floor().toString().padLeft(2, '0');
  });
});

// At Recording Stop :

timerSubscription!.cancel();
timerStream = null;
setState(() {
  minutesStr = '00';
  secondsStr = '00';
});

// Display Timer :

Text('$minutesStr:$secondsStr')

// Handle timeStream

  Stream<int> stopWatchStream() {
    StreamController<int>? streamController;
    Timer? timer;
    Duration timerInterval = Duration(seconds: 1);
    int counter = 0;

    void stopTimer() {
      if (timer != null) {
        timer!.cancel();
        timer = null;
        counter = 0;
        streamController!.close();
      }
    }

    void tick(_) {
      counter++;
      streamController!.add(counter);
    }

    void startTimer() {
      timer = Timer.periodic(timerInterval, tick);
    }

    streamController = StreamController<int>(
      onListen: startTimer,
      onCancel: stopTimer,
      onResume: startTimer,
      onPause: stopTimer,
    );

    return streamController.stream;
  }
```

Comment: ok , thanks for answer , but why are you calling stop in tick method , this causes the end of stream as soon as its started ( steam will stop at second 1)

Comment: Good catch.  I have edited. Thanks. I forgot to remove it from tick().